# Higher Order Function returned function with passed on argument as variable instead of hard coded values, Why?

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function makePredicateFunc(min, max){
  return function(num){
     return num >= min && num <= max;
  }
}
 
const isChild = makePredicateFunc(0,17);
console.log(isChild);
```

```
// Output
ƒ (num) {
    return num >= min && num <= max;
}
```

Why the output mentions min and max variable name instead of values 0 and 17  ?

**min, max** variable **should have** replaced with hard coded values

// Output should be like this
f(num) {
return num >= 0 && num <= 17;
}

Comment: Try logging the result of `isChild(6)`, `isChild(-1)` and `isChild(18)`  and see if you get the behavior you expect.

Comment: That was intentional.  I didn't want to execute isChild() i wanted to see isChild's function definition

Comment: does the function reference that `isChild()`  holds, continues to have access to parent or higher order' function (whatever that called) level variables?